Problem using HP USB-C G5 dock with display port
My laptop is Asus Tuf F15 with i7-12H CPU and Nvidia GTX 3060 GPU. I have just began using Ubuntu 24.01 LTS and am quite newbie with it. I have two basic LG monitors with DP 1.4 and HDMI 2.0 and would use HP USB-C G5 dock that has two DP ports and one HDMI port to connect them.
However, when I connected the displays with DP cable to the dock and the dock to my laptop’s thunderbolt port, the displays were recognized with name ’Nvidia’ and the resolution was 640x480 and it was not possible to change through the settings.
When I connect the monitors with HDMI the resolutions are correct and the displays recognized correctly as ”LG …”.
Also, I think the dock is not properly identified as the power button on it cannot be used to turn on the laptop.
Could anyone help me troubleshoot this or provide solution? I would very much like the dock to serve its full funtion.
Update: even when connecting monitor with HDMI to the dock, I have experienced problems and needed to reboot as the system freezes occacionally.
